# Since when the M-x shell open the shell on the other buffer?

Tags: shell

I recently noticed the `M-x shell` command opens the shell in the other buffer.

I used to do `Ctrl-x 3` > `Ctrl-x o` > `M-x shell`.

But recently I found that `M-x shell` opens the shell in the other buffer.
Was it changed? Or is there any possible mis-configuration?

Comment: This was changed in emacs 25 afaik